# An order type $\tau$ equal to its power $\tau^n, n>2$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

In this question we are concerned only with [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) (aka total)  [order types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type). By a [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of an order type we understand a cardinality of an instance of this type, which obviously does not depend on selection of such particular instance. Some of the order types that occur most often and have particularly nice properties are [ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) (which are order types of [well-orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)) and their well-known and prominent subset, finite ordinals (aka [natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers) $\mathbb{N}$).

Recall that:

- $0, 1, 2, \dots$ — unique linear order type for each finite cardinality.
- $\omega$ — the order type of $\mathbb{N}$ ordered by magnitude, the smallest infinite ([denumerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denumerable)) ordinal.
- $\omega_1$ — the order type of the set of all countable ordinals, ordered by "is initial segment of" relation (or, equivalently, by $\in$ relation). It is the smallest [uncountable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) ordinal, the initial ordinal of the 2nd infinite [cardinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) $\aleph_1$.
- $\eta$ — the [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order) countable order type of [rational numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_numbers) $\mathbb{Q}$ ordered my their magnitude, which is also an order type of *any* dense denumerable linear order without first and last elements (e.g. the set of positive algebraic numbers).

The sum and product of order types are natural generalizations of (and are consistent with) the [sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Addition) and [product of ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication), which we consider well-known. These operations are associative, but in general, not commutative. For example: $\eta+1 \ne 1+\eta\ne\eta$, but $\eta+1+\eta=\eta+\eta=\eta=\eta\cdot\eta=\eta\cdot\omega=(\eta+1)\cdot\omega\ne\omega\cdot\eta$ (the last order being not dense). Of course $\eta\cdot\omega_1\ne\eta$ because of different cardinality, although every proper initial segment of $\eta\cdot\omega_1$ is $\eta$ or $\eta+1$. Note that $\eta\cdot\omega_1=(\eta + 1)\cdot\omega_1\ne(1+\eta)\cdot\omega_1$, and even $(1+\eta)\cdot\omega_1\ne1+\eta\cdot\omega_1$, although $(1+\eta)\cdot\omega=1+\eta$. We agree that a positive integer power of an order type is just a syntactic shortcut for repeated multiplication.

There are some order types satisfying $\tau^2=\tau$, for example: $0, 1, \eta, \omega\cdot\eta$ and $\omega^2\cdot\eta$.

> *Question:* Is there a linear order type $\tau$ such that $\tau^2\ne\tau$, but $\tau^n=\tau$ for some integer $n>2$?

Comment: For a negative answer, it will suffice to rule out countable order types like that, since any uncountable order type can be made countable in a forcing extension to which the calculation of $\tau^n$ is absolute.

Comment: @JDH: Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting a change in the  question, so much as a strategy to answer your original question.

Comment: But your comment implies that the updated question is equivalent to the old version without the word 'countable', right?

Comment: My comment seems to show only that if we can prove that there is no countable counterexample (which is what I expect), then we can prove that there is no counterexample of any cardinality. Perhaps one can improve the idea, using countable substructures, to show that the questions are equivalent.

Comment: But suppose the opposite: that there are such examples. Then it is not possible that the least cardinality of such an example is not countable (i.e. there are no countable examples). So in both cases we could safely add 'countable' to narrow down the search, right?

Comment: The "then it is not possible" part of your argument is exactly where I see one using a countable-elementary substructure. My argument was using provability of the claim, since it was applying the question in a forcing extension of the universe, a different universe.

Comment: Both forms of the question are interesting, and my expectation is that they will both be settled negatively.  But one doesn't replace a question with another just because they have the same answer. E.g. most people would not be willing to replace the question "Is there a compact totally disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}$?" with the question "Does 1+1=2?", even though they have the same answer. Rather, the argument that they have the same answer is part of the solution to the first question.

Comment: Is the statement that $(\omega\eta)^2=\omega\eta$ correct? It looks to me like $(\omega\eta)^2=\omega^2\eta$; are these equal?  Also, would an example of the weaker "$\tau\ne \tau^2$, but there exist distinct $n,m>0$ such that $\tau^n = \tau^m$" be any good?  (Note that this statement actually implies that that there exists a $\tau$ having the property originally asked for, or there exists a $\tau$ with $\tau \ne \tau^2$ but $\tau^n = \tau^{n+1}$ for some $n$.)

Comment: Oh, I see, they're both equal to $1+\eta$, aren't they.

Comment: @HarryAltman: $\omega \cdot \eta \ne 1 + \eta$ because the left side is not dense. $(\omega \cdot \eta)^2=(\omega \cdot \eta) \cdot (\omega \cdot \eta)=\omega \cdot ((\eta \cdot \omega) \cdot \eta)=\omega \cdot (\eta \cdot \eta)=\omega \cdot \eta$. Here we used $\eta \cdot \omega=\eta$ and $\eta \cdot \eta = \eta$. These identities are true because every countable dense linear order without ends is isomorphic to $\eta$.

Comment: Oops, yes, my mistake. For some reason when thinking about this I wrote $\eta\omega=\omega$ instead of $\eta\omega=\eta$.  I also evidently got confused in thinking about $\omega\eta$.

Comment: could you explain or give example about (η+1) (1+η) ??

Comment: Is it known that such an order must contain $\eta$? I feel there should be an argument related to decomposing scattered linear orderings which uses the situation on ordinals.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Moderators cannot move questions past a certain age. I would suggest that you repost the question (in more concise form) on MO and link to this question.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks, I reposted it at http://mathoverflow.net/q/149117/9550

Comment: This question was considered without result by the ancients. From Sierpiński's *Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers* second edition revised, Warszawa 1965, p. 235: "We do not know so far any example of two types $\varphi$ and $\psi$, such that $\varphi^2=\psi^2$ but $\varphi^3\ne\psi^3$, or types $\gamma$ and $\delta$ such that $\gamma^2\ne\delta^2$ but $\gamma^3=\delta^3$. Neither do we know any type $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2\ne\alpha^3=\alpha$." The context is linear order types of arbitrary cardinality.

Comment: I've retreated from my claim that the general case reduces to the  countable case, since the argument I had in mind seems incorrect to me now, for I don't see why the forcing to make $\tau$ countable can't also add an unwanted isomorphism of  $\tau^2$ with $\tau$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such questions have been considered in the past. From W. Sierpiński's *Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers*, second edition revised, Warszawa 1965, p. 235: "We do not know so far any example of two types $\varphi$ and $\psi$, such that $\varphi^2=\psi^2$ but $\varphi^3\ne\psi^3$, or types $\gamma$ and $\delta$ such that $\gamma^2\ne\delta^2$ but $\gamma^3=\delta^3$. Neither do we know any type $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2\ne\alpha^3=\alpha$." Also, from p. 254: "We do not know whether there exist two different denumerable order types which are left-hand divisors of each other. Neither do we know whether there exist two different order types which are both left-hand and right-hand divisors of each other." Of course, if $\tau^n=\tau$ for some integer $n\gt2$, then $\tau^2$ and $\tau=\tau^2\tau^{n-2}=\tau^{n-2}\tau^2$ are both left-hand and right-hand divisors of each other.

For what it's worth, here is a partial answer to your question, for a very special class of order types. By "order type" I mean *linear* order type. An order type $\xi$ is said to have a "first element" if it's the type of an ordered set with a first element, i.e., if $\xi=1+\psi$ for some $\psi$; the same goes for "last element".

**Proposition.** If $\alpha$ is a countable order type, and if $\alpha\xi=\alpha$ for some order type $\xi$ with no first or last element, then $\alpha\beta=\alpha$ for every countable order type $\beta\ne0$.

**Corollary.** If $\tau$ is a countable order type with no first or last element, and if $\tau^n=\tau$ for some integer $n\gt1$, then $\tau^2=\tau$.

The corollary is obtained by setting $\alpha=\beta=\tau$ and $\xi=\tau^{n-1}$ in the proposition.

The proposition is proved by a modified form of Cantor's back-and-forth argument. Namely, let $A$ be an ordered set of type $\alpha=\alpha\xi$, and let $B$ be an ordered set of type $\alpha\beta$. An isomorphism between $A$ and $B$ will be constructed as the union of a chain of partial isomorphisms $f_k$ of the following form. The domain of $f_k$ is $I_1\cup I_2\cup\dots\cup I_k$, where $I_1,\dots,I_k$ are intervals in $A$ of order type $\alpha$; $I_1\lt\dots\lt I_k$; the interval in $A$ between $I_j$ and $I_{j+1}$ ($1\le j\lt k$), as well as the interval to the left of $I_1$ and the interval to the right of $I_k$, have order types which are nonzero right multiples of $\alpha$. The range of $f_k$ is $J_1\cup\dots\cup J_k$ where $J_1,\dots,J_k$ are intervals in $B$ of type $\alpha$, etc. etc. etc., and $f(I_1)=J_1,\dots,f(I_k)=J_k$.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't actually answer the question asked, admittedly, but I'm posting it as an answer since it does answer a related question.

We can ask more generally, can we find an order $\tau$ such that there exist distinct $n$ and $m$ such that $\tau^n=\tau^m$, other than those satisfying $\tau=\tau^2$?  Note that if we have such a $\tau$, then either there exists some $n$ such that $\tau^n=\tau^{n+1}$, or by taking an appropriate power of $\tau$ we can find an order that actually answers the original question.

Well, as I said, I don't have an example of the latter, but I do have an example of the former. Let $\tau=\omega(\eta+1)$.  Since $(\eta+1)\omega=\eta$, we get $\tau^2=\omega\eta$, and similarly $\tau^3=\omega\eta=\tau^2$.  But $\omega(\eta+1)\ne\omega\eta$ as the former has a final segment isomorphic to $\omega$ and the latter doesn't (as one way to see why, note that any final segment contains a copy of $\omega2$).

So at least there exists $\tau$ with $\tau^3=\tau^2$ but not $\tau^2=\tau$, though that doesn't seem to yield an answer to the original question.